# Microsoft GraphAPI - behavior with emails received from alias email addresses

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api, alias

I am looking for validation of what I was able to compile on the various forums + chatGPT.

My case: I have a primary address and associated secondary addresses (aliases).

I use Microsoft GraphAPI to process incoming emails.

Do I need to create a subscription on the alias to receive emails via the GraphAPI? or a subscription to the main mailbox is enough?

In what we receive from GraphAPI, do we have the information of the alias address and the main email? or only the alias email address and you have to use a GETuser proxyAddresses method to retrieve the main address?